# LWJGL VBO content is always drawn to the center of the screen (0,0,0)

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, vbo, opengl-2.0

I started to follow a tutorial about modern OpenGL rendering and altered the c++ code from a VBO lesson to work with LWJGL. I initialized the VBO with the following code:

```
int vbo = GL15.glGenBuffers();
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

"buffer" is initialized as

```
FloatBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(9);
```

and then filled with {-0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 0, 0.5f, 0} via

```
buffer.put(val)
```

My game loop looks like this:

```
GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_POINTS, 0, 3);
GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
Display.update();
```

But all I get is a white dot in the center of the screen. I found a similar question ([VBO: Array not drawn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604594/vbo-array-not-drawn)), but the solution did not fix my problem.
The tutorial I used is http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial02/tutorial02.html and http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial03/tutorial03.html. When I try to draw GL_TRIANGLES instead of GL_POINTS, nothing is drawn onto the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wasting hours reading different tutorials, I figured out that I did not rewind() my buffer...

```
GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

and

```
GL11.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

as suggested in [VBO: Array not drawn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604594/vbo-array-not-drawn) was not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use `glTranslate*()` to set a position where you want to draw something. It can be sorta deprecated, but it works.
[Here](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=26564.0) you can find a discussion about it.
Your code should look the following way:

> glPushMatrix();
>   glTranslate*();
>   //draw something
>   glPopMatrix();

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the point of the tutorial is to not use the fixed function pipeline anymore.
Anyway, your approach is working, but I want to stick with VBOs.

Comment: If you want to draw your object in other place, you definitely have to pass displacement value to the video adapter. You can use `glTranslate*()` for it. It will be of no sense to store this data in video memory since it is likely to be changed next frame.

Comment: This is true, but you may want to store some vertices in a buffer to reuse them as much as you want without creating them every time you want to draw them at different scales, positions etc. To achieve this, I tried to create a VBO with all vertices and then "translate" the whole VBO.

Comment: Sorry, it seems like I don't understand something. Your VBO should stay the same through the render cycles, but all you need is to change the drawing position? right?